# What does *. do in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and I don't know what `*.` does in Groovy.

I cannot share the code snippet as it's against company policy but it is used like:

```
instanceOfSomeDomainClass*.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

`*.` in Groovy is know as the "spread dot" operator. It will iterate a collection calling the method that follows it.

So in your example it would iterate the collection `instanceOfSomeDomainClass` and call `someMethod()` on each entry in the collection.

Here is a [blog post](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory) that goes into further examples of how it can be used.

Comment: So it's basically a `map` operator?

Answer (score 0):

Also, the `spread dot` has a semantic of `collect()` method:

```
list*.someField == list.collect{ it.someField }
```

In case of method invocation, you will get a collection of those methods results